# Want to see if a one digit of a 2 digit number is divisible by the other digit

Tags: c++, c++17

The problem I am having is how to say if(//code=Whole) I dont know how to tell the program if the number equals whole number because if its a number like 39 9 divided 3 equals a whole number if a number is not divisible it will go to the decimals which is how I am willing to solve the problem by saying if digit 1 or 2 divisible by the other digit is whole then cout<<Divisible

I tried searching up didnt work heres my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x,z,n;
cin>>x;
x%10=z;
x/10=n;
if(z/n==int)
{
    cout<<"YES";
}
else if(n/z==int)
{
    cout<<"YES"
}
else
{
    cout<<"NO";
}
}
```

I dont know how to say if it equals whole So i dont know what to put there plus there might be something wrong in the program other than that.

Comment: Are you familiar with the modulo operator (%)?

Comment: More basic, are you familiar with *error messages* ? This code has plenty of them. `x%10=z;`, for example, is not a valid statement in C++. That should (likely) be `z=x%10;`. Get a book on C++, because some of these mistakes are fundamental.

Comment: @blackbrandt Somewhere the OP got the idea to use `%`, although the assignment statements are backwards...

Answer (score 2):

This is your code.

```
int main()
{
    int x,z,n;
    cin>>x;
    x%10=z;
    x/10=n;
    if(z/n==int)
    {
        cout<<"YES";
    }
    else if(n/z==int)
    {
        cout<<"YES"
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"NO";
    }
}
```

A few things. First, please use whitespace to make your code readable. It's going to safe you from a wide variety of bugs over the years.

Next, this is bad code:

```
    x%10=z;
    x/10=n;
```

So is this:

```
    if(z/n==int)
```

The first few lines of your main method should be like this:

```
 int x;
 cin >> x;

 int z = x % 10;
 int n = x / 10;
```

Note that I've done two things. First, I moved where the variables are declared to as late as possible so that they aren't hanging around, uninitialized for a while. This is just good practice. Define them and assign them at the same time.

Next, the way you wrote that code doesn't make sense. An assignment statement can't be written backwards the way you did it.

In your head, you could say, "z becomes x % 10" if you have to.

This line won't compile:

```
    if(z/n==int)
```

If you want to see if z divides evenly by n:

```
    if ( z % n == 0 )
```

You have the same problem in the else-if a few lines later.

Comment: That is not bad code, that is invalid code. There is a difference between bad habits and low quality code to code that won't even compile. And there is a lot of the latter in the question.

Comment: @JakobStark You're faulting my semantics?

Comment: I intended to politely recommend using the wording "invalid code" instead of "bad code" in your answer. To me "bad" sounds like "you're not recommended to do it" whereas "invalid" means "you cannot ever do that". So it was a mere wording suggestion to your answer;)

Comment: It still doesnt work @JosephLarson I found out the problem was if a bigger number is first it wont work like if its 84 it will say no but 48 yes i tried fixing this but it just made the code worse.

Comment: @hazey Without an updated version of your code with the fixes I've talked about, I don't know what else to tell you.